# Open EXISTING xls in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an existing file (C:\wb.xls) that I want to open and make changes to.  How in Apachie POI do you open an existing file?  All the documentation that I find has to go with creating a new file.  And if you know, how do you insert a new row at the top of the xls file or how to autoformat column widths?

Comment: See if this tutorial helps: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

Answer (score 23):

Use one among the following

```
 XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(xlFileAddress));
```

OR

```
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(xlFileAddress));
```

OR

```
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(xlFileAddress));
```

and then use wb for creating/reading/updating sheets/rows/cell whatever you want. For detail visit [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).  This will definitely help you.

Comment: Note that [opening from an `InputStream` is slower and requires more memory than opening from a `File`, as explained in the POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Comment: Note if using maven you need to have dependency of poi-ooxml rather than just poi to use the WorkbookFactory class.

Answer (score 11):

Did you try reading the [Apache POI HowTo "Reading or modifying an existing file"](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api)? That should cover you...

Basically, what you'll want to do is taken from the [QuickGuide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) eg [this for loading a File](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("MyExcel.xls"));
Sheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);

// Get the 11th row, creating if not there
Row r1 = s.getRow(10);
if (r1 == null) r1 = s.createRow(10);

// Get the 3rd column, creating if not there
Cell c2 = r1.getCell(2, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
// Set a string to be the value
c2.setCellValue("Hello, I'm the cell C10!");

// Save
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("New.xls");
wb.write(out);
out.close();
```