# Java and POI:Creating a new Excel Sheet no overwriting

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

my question is pretty simple or dumb. 
Well I have a method this method is called several times
but every single time i call it I would like to create a new sheet on the same Excel file "Writefile"
I know that every single time I call the method I'm actually overwriting the `Writefile`.
Can someone help me to keep this method but instead of overwriting,I like to add an new sheet

```
 public static void write(int t, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List X, String Writefile,int repeat,List<String> Sheetname) {
        String excelFileName = Writefile;
        String sheetName = (String) X.get(0);// name of sheet based on the Content of the List
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);
        //some details 
}
```

Comment: Load the file instead of creating a new one?

Comment: How can I Do so ? just a beginner on POI

Comment: you want add sheet to you existing excel file?

Comment: yes every single time i call the method another sheet will be created and added to the existing excel file

Comment: Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556108/open-existing-xls-in-apache-poi) to open existing

Comment: Read the Apache POI docs? eg http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream