# How to add multiple sheets to same workbook using POI java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create Excel report using POI. I want to add multiple sheets to my excel workbook but my workbook is overwritten each time the method runs. 
Method to write data to excel - called 3 times and only last report exists in excel

```
public void createReportFile(MultiValueMap MMReport) {
        try {
            workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            sheet = workBook.createSheet("REPTRANS_TRN" + count);

            AtomicInteger rowCounter = new AtomicInteger();
            MMReport.forEach((k, v) -> {
                AtomicInteger cellCounter = new AtomicInteger();
                Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCounter.incrementAndGet());
                row.createCell(cellCounter.getAndIncrement()).setCellValue(k.toString());

                List<String> values = (List<String>) v;
                values.forEach(value -> {
                    row.createCell(cellCounter.getAndIncrement()).setCellValue(value.toString());
                });
            });
            fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(getReportFile());
            workBook.write(fileOutput);
            fileOutput.flush();
            fileOutput.close();
            ++count;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Method to create new file

```
 public File getReportFile() throws IOException {
        File buildFileFolder;

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();

        String rootDirectory = "Reports";       //main_folder_name
        String dailyFolderName = dateFormat.format(date);       //Daily folder name

        File dailyFileFolder = new File(rootDirectory + "/" + dailyFolderName);
        if (!dailyFileFolder.exists()) {
            dailyFileFolder.mkdirs();
            POIforgfgWrite.resetCounterValue("buildcounter");
            buildNumber = 1;
        }

        String buildFileName = "RentRun-Build-" + buildNumber;
        buildFileFolder = new File(rootDirectory + "/" + dailyFolderName + "/" + buildFileName + ".xlsx");
        if (!buildFileFolder.exists()) {
            buildFileFolder.createNewFile();
            POIforgfgWrite.writeBackCounterValue("buildcounter", buildNumber);
        }
        return buildFileFolder;
    }
```

Comment: `workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();` you overwrite the existing workbook on every call

Comment: Can you please let me know how to refer existing workbook and add a sheet to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17570564/7109162 But normally there shouldn't be a need to reopen the workbook as this means that you close it during runtime.

Comment: Tried and got following exception - org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)

Comment: Its not clear to me how the flow of your program is as well as the variable scope. **Maybe** you can also just remove the line `workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();`

Comment: Got it working as expected. Created workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(); at class level. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

Your `createReportFile()` method is creating a new Workbook instance, creating one sheet in it, writing data to it, then closing and saving it with `name + counter`.
On every call to `createReportFile`, **you create a new, single sheet Workbook**.

The `counter` variable seems to be from a class scope, which might be what you want your Workbook instance to be. You should also open the Workbook in the same scope that you close it.

I suggest you create an `updateReportFile()` method that receives a Workbook instance obtained beforehand and your data to be written. For your Workbook you should provide the OutputStream-object  (given that it exists, otherwise create a new one) that you wish to update/create.